# iPhone app developed by me and submitted by client?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I am finishing an app for my client.
He wants to submit it to Apple himself.

What must I do ?

Should I give him the app unsigned ?
Should I ask him a provisioning profile ?
Should I be added to his team and to his Distribution Profile ?

Thanks a lot for your help ?

Thierry

Comment: ---- UPDATE ----

My client has signed up for iPhone Devleoper Program and he wants to submit the app under his name.

And I don't want to give the source code. Is it possible ?

Comment: I have the same situation, I had my client sign up for the developer account and add me as one of the developers and I did everything else from then on.  I submitted the app using his account, his certificate and his provisioning profile.  The client did not even have to be involved with any of the messiness.  His company gets the credit for the app but I got paid anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Have your client sign up for the iPhone Developer Program so that way when your client submits the app to the App Store it will be under the client's company name.  You can still manage all the code signing and provisioning for your client if they do not know how to do this stuff.  The client can simply give u access to their developer account to handle all that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would just give him the source code, unless you specifically don't want to do that for some reason. That way, he can just compile it himself.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done for clients who want to submit to Apple themselves:

- The client must create (or you can create for them if they give you their login info) the app store distribution profile for the app and send it to you.    Requires some communication between you and client to make sure they use the right app id, etc.
- (I think you may need the client's developer certificate as well in order for them to "own" the app -- not 100% sure about this)
- Don't forget to also get the private key file as the certificate signing won't work without it
- I set the client cert / app store dist profile into the app and build the app for app store.
- Deliver the binary to the client.
- Client uploads to itunes connect.